# BiometricPrompt Android: UnrecoverableKeyException on Samsung after software or security updates

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

Posting here for the first time, wish me luck :)

We have developed a support of biometric authentication in our mobile app using BiometricPrompt API. We decided to go with CryptoObjects as it allows us to comply with regulations.

After implementation we are facing an issue that on Samsung devices and on some Huawei devices after some device software updates and after almost every Security Patch we are getting:

```
Caused by java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain information about key
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.getKeyCharacteristics(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:238)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:360)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:116)
       at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062)
       at com.*****.mobile.data.crypto.CryptoRepositoryImpl.getSignature(CryptoRepositoryImpl.java:527)
       at com.*****.mobile.business.biometric.authentication.BiometricAuthenticationPromptInteractorImpl$getSignatureForAuthentication$1.subscribe(BiometricAuthenticationPromptInteractorImpl.java:52)

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: User authentication required
       at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1151)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.getKeyCharacteristics(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:240)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:360)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:116)
       at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062)
```

This forces us generating a new key pair, leading to a terrible user experience.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? And can suggest what needs to be changed/considered to prevent our key getting invalidated/corrupted after Samsung security patches?

We are generating a key pair using following code
*(fallback is used as we discovered that cheaper Samsung devices not supporting EC, hence we use RSA on such devices)*:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun createSigningKey(keyBaseName: KeyBaseName, useFallbackAlgorithm: Boolean): Either<Throwable, JavaPublicKey> = try {
  deleteKey(keyBaseName)
  when {
    useFallbackAlgorithm -> KeyPairGenerator
        .getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEY_STORE_PROVIDER)
        .apply {
          initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyBaseName, PURPOSE_SIGN or PURPOSE_VERIFY)
              .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(KEY_SIZE, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
              .setDigests(DIGEST_SHA256, DIGEST_SHA512)
              .setSignaturePaddings(SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
              .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
              .build())
        }
    else -> KeyPairGenerator
        .getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, ANDROID_KEY_STORE_PROVIDER)
        .apply {
          initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyBaseName, PURPOSE_SIGN or PURPOSE_VERIFY)
              .setDigests(DIGEST_SHA256, DIGEST_SHA512)
              .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
              .build())
        }
  }.generateKeyPair()
      .public
      .right()
} catch (e: Exception) {
  firebaseRepository.logException(RuntimeException("createSigningKey", e))
  e.left()
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: so... what is exactly your question? "why are samsung phones problematic like this?" perhaps?

Comment: Hello! The question is whether it is possible to avoid that our key gets corrupted/invalidated after device software update or security patch :( as no Android specification describes it as a normal behavior.

Comment: Perhaps Samsung's android specification does? this is a very vendor-specific question as it seems. Since both Samsung and Huawei are (terribly) known for using stuff that regular vanilla android simply does not have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement below 2 solutions to see if it works for you.

1. Add allowBackup false to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
...
>
```

2. Android keystore is not thread-safe, please wrap all your Android keystore operations with `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: For more details, please refer to my article https://medium.com/@weidianhuang/how-to-write-thread-safe-code-for-android-keystore-40a0fa17f416